# How do I add nopin="nopin" to the default avatar?

Tags: customization, avatar, gravatar

I noticed that if someone clicks on my Pinterest share button on a blog post, several unrelated images show up. I was able to use *nopin="nopin"* per [Pinterest's documentation](https://help.pinterest.com/en/business/article/prevent-saves-to-pinterest-from-your-site) on most of these images to clean most of it up.

However, I have a custom avatar set in my functions.php...

```
//* Add new default gravatar to Settings » Discussion page */
add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'wpb_new_gravatar' );
function wpb_new_gravatar ($avatar_defaults) {
$myavatar = 'https://www.fakedomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/PiggyBank.jpg';
$avatar_defaults[$myavatar] = "Default Gravatar";
return $avatar_defaults;
}
```

If someone gets that avatar in a comment, then the image shows up as a choice on a Pinterest share. How do I add the *nopin="nopin"* attribute to this avatar image?

I [found a similar post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157044/how-do-i-add-a-custom-html-attribute-to-get-avatar) discussing this issue, but it's way over my head and seems a little different because he's using an array (lol, also over my head).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
function wp_ste_add_nopin_args( $args ) {
    $extra_attr = 'nopin="nopin"';
    $args['extra_attr'] = $extra_attr;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'get_avatar_data', 'wp_ste_add_nopin_args', 999, 1 );
```

For further reading, please visit: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar_data/

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks you!

There is a small typo in it though if you want to update it for others. You're missing an apostrophe before the semicolon on the nopin line. It should read:

$extra_attr = 'nopin="nopin"';

Thanks again - very much appreciated, @Tommy !!

Comment: @Jim updated :) thanks